# Representation $A$ of a group $G$ on a vector space ${\mathbb{V}}$ is equiv. to a representation on the maps $\varphi:\, G\longrightarrow{\mathbb{V}}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups

Consider a group $\,G\,$, a vector space $\,{\mathbb{V}}\,$, and a space $\,{\mathbb{W}}\,$ of maps $\,\varphi:\,G\longrightarrow{\mathbb{V}}\,$. In the space $\,{\mathbb{W}}\,$, acts a natural representation
  $$
  U_g\varphi(x)=\varphi({g^{-1}}x)~~,\qquad g,\,x\in G~~.
  $$
 It is easy to prove (see below) that an arbitrary representation $\,A(G)\,$ on $\,{\mathbb{V}}\,$,
 $$
 A~:\quad G~\longrightarrow~GL({\mathbb{V}})~~,
 $$
 is equivalent to the representation $U$ on ${\mathbb{W}}$. This, however, seems to entail a paradoxical result that all representations on ${\mathbb{V}}$ are equivalent. (Or does it not?) I must be missing something here.

Now, the **Proof**.

Introduce an operator
 $$
 {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\,:\quad{\mathbb{V}}\,\longrightarrow\,{\mathbb{W}}
 $$
 mapping an element $\,v\in{\mathbb{V}}\,$ to a function $\,\varphi\in{\mathbb{W}}\,$,
 $$
 \varphi(x)~=~( {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\,v)\,(x)~~,
 $$
  where $\,x\in G\,$ is a free variable. We set the mapping as
 $$
 \varphi(1)\,=\,v~~,\quad\varphi(x)\,=\,A(x^{-1})\,v~~.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
 $$
 The operator $\,{\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\,$ is invertible, because

$ \mbox{(a)} \;\;\forall\varphi\in{\mathbb{W}}\,, ~\exists~{\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}^{-1}:~\varphi\,\longrightarrow\,\varphi(1)~,~~ \mbox{so} ~~ {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}~ \mbox{is surjective},
 $

$
 \mbox{(b)} \;\;\operatorname{Ker}\, {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\,=\, 0\,, ~~\mbox{so} ~~{\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}~ \mbox{is injective}.
 $

(For $\,v\neq\vec{\,0}\,$ and $\,\operatorname{det} A(x^{-1})\neq 0\,$, we always get a nonzero $\,A(x^{-1})\, v\,$.)

Similarly, a vector $\,A(g)v\,$, for a fixed $\, g\in G\,$, will be mapped by $\, {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\,$ to a function
 $$
 \varphi^{\,\prime}(x)\,=\,( {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\, A(g)\, v\,)\,(x)
 $$
 such that
 $$
 \varphi^{\,\prime}(1)\,=\,A(g)v\,~,\quad\varphi^{\,\prime}(x)\,=\,A(x^{-1})\,A(g)\,v\,~.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)
 $$
 We now can write
 $$
 U_g\,( {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\,v)\,(x)\,=\,U_g\,\varphi(x)~=~\varphi (g^{-1}x)~=~A(\,(g^{-1}x)^{-1}\,)\,v
 $$
 where, at the last step, we used definition (1) with $\,g^{-1}x\,$ used instead of $\,x\,$. With aid of (2), the above can be continued as
 $$
 =\,A(x^{-1})\,A(g)\,v~=~\varphi^{\,\prime}(g)\,=\,( {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\, A(g)\, v\,)\,(x)~~,
 $$
 so $\, {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\,$ is an intertwiner:
 $$
 U\, {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\,=\, {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\, A~~.
 $$
 Moreover, since $\, {\mathfrak{M}}_{{_{\rm{A}}}}\,$ is invertible, the representations $\,A\,$ and $\,U\,$ are equivalent. Thus we have proven a somewhat counterintuitive **Theorem**:

Any representation $\, A(G)\,$ on the elements $\,v\,$ of a space $\,{\mathbb{V}}\,$ is equivalent to the natural representation $\, U_g\varphi(x)=\varphi(g^{-1}x)\,$ on the maps $\,\varphi:\, G\longrightarrow{\mathbb{V}}\,$.

This result looks suspicious.

Indeed, were an arbitrary representation $\,A(G)\,$ on $\,{\mathbb{V}}\,$ equivalent to $\,U(G)\,$ on $\,{\mathbb{W}}\,$ of maps, would this not ensure the mutual equivalence of all representations on $\,{\mathbb{V}}\,$? That would be hard to believe.

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Unless the group is trivial the two spaces do not even have the same dimension.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That I understand. Still, where exactly did I make an oversight? For each vector $v$, there exists a map $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(1)=v$ and the rest of $\varphi$ is defined by the representation $A$. Then we build a morphism which is invertible and has its Ker $= 0$. Where did I take a wrong turn?

Comment: Since it was so clearly not true, I did not look through the very brief arguments. If you write it out in detail, rather than shortcutting it, you will see that the surjectivity argument is not correct.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  This argument is as follows: there exists ${\mathfrak{M}}^{-1}$ which maps each function $\varphi$ to its value at $g=1$. Is this wrong?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Would it be right of me to say that in reality ${\mathfrak{M}}$ is not an isomorphism but a monomorphism, because it maps the vector space ${\mathbb{V}}$ not to the entire space of maps ${\mathbb{W}}$ but to a subset (subspace?) thereof?

Comment: You can certainly define $\mathfrak{N} \varphi = \varphi(1)$, and obviously $\mathfrak{N} \mathfrak{M}$ is the identity on $\mathbb{V}$. But what you actually need is to show $\mathfrak{M} \mathfrak{N}$ is the identity on $\mathbb{W}$, and $\varphi(1) = \psi(1)$ does not imply $\varphi = \psi$.

Comment: @aschepler You probably want to say that there exists functions $\psi$ such that $\psi(1)=\phi(1)$, while $\psi(g)\neq A(g^{-1}) \psi(1)$. Correct? Stated differently, my ${\mathfrak{M}}$ maps ${\mathbb{V}}$ not to ${\mathbb{W}}$ but to its subspace; hence the lack of surjectivity. Right?